# Caml query filer by content type and field value

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

I need to make a Caml query to filter a list from content type AND for a specific value from a list. For example, a content type ID and a field value "English" from the column "languages" will get all the data/rows from the list with said content type and where languages is equal to "English".

So far I have this:

```
         `<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='BannerImageUrl' />
        <FieldRef Name='intraSubhead' /><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><FieldRef Name='Title' />
        <FieldRef Name='intraContentCategory' /></ViewFields>
        <Query>
        <Where>
        <And>
        <BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/>
        <Value Type='ContentTypeId'>${contentTypeId}  //I load the content type here

        <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="intraLanguages" />
        </Value>
         <Value Type="TaxonomyFieldType">${currentLanguage} // value like "English" and so on.
        </Value>
        </Eq>
        </And>
        </BeginsWith>

        </Where></Query>
        </View>`;
```

As seen above I try to do filter with content type and a value in a taxonomy field (intraLanguages). It doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Are you getting any error? If yes, please post it to your question. Also I can see the error in your query. Ending tags are not closed properly.

Comment: Your XML is malformed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Content Type**:

You can add filter on Content Type using its name or Id as given below:

```
//Using Name of Content Type
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='ContentType'/>
    <Value Type='Computed'>YourCustomContentTypeName</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>

//Using ID of Content Type
<Where>
  <BeginsWith>
     <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />
     <Value  Type='ContentTypeId'>YourContentTypeIdHere</Value>
  </BeginsWith>
</Where>
```

**For Managed Metadata field**:

There are 2 methods to query a list/library that contains a managed metadata column:

1. Query against Term Name
2. Query Against WSSID

Method 1 (will look something similar to this):

```
 query.Query = @"<Where>
                  <Contains>
                      <FieldRef Name='" + MyTaxonomyFieldName + @"' />
                      <Value Type='Text'>" + tagName + @"</Value>
                  </Contains>
                </Where>";
```

Or

```
<Query><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ManagedMetadata\"/><Value type=\"string\">brocoli</Value></Eq></Query>
```

Method 2:

```
query.Query = @"<Where>
                  <In>
                   <FieldRef LookupId='TRUE' Name='" + MyTaxonomyField + @"' />
                    <Values>
                       <Value Type='Integer'>" + tagLookupID + @"</Value>
                    </Values>
                  </In>
                 </Where>";
```

It is recommended to use the second method to avoid situations where the term name is used under different term groups.